# Low Limit Topology

Tags: general-topology

Recall that Rl is the lower limit topology on R; that is, it has basis consisting of intervals of the form [, )
 (a) Show that the infinite intervals [2, ∞) and (−∞, 4) are open in Rl 
(b) Generalize what you did in part (a) by showing the infinite intervals [a, ∞) and (−∞, ) are open in Rl for any real numbers , .

I know that [2, ∞) is element which is belonged to basis of lower limit topology then it is open. For (−∞, 4) = [1, 4) U [0, 4) U ... U [i,4) i ->−∞ then open. Is it correct. Also please help part b.
Thanks

Comment: $[2,\infty)$ is just the union of $[2,n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: You basically know how to do it, but you seem not to know what to do. To show that a set is open, you do not have to show that it is in the basis. (e.g. $[2,\infty)$ is NOT in the basis but it is open.) What you have to do is express each of those sets in terms of an arbitrary union of elements in the basis, because the basis generates the open sets. You just have to reuse your strategy for the first part on the second part.